# Textarea - prevent user from inserting more than one line break

Tags: jquery, line-breaks

I have the following function to get the value in a textarea with the id #posttext and to call a function to post something.

I do not want the user to be able to type in more than one line break **in a row**. How can I prevent that?

Here's the code:

```
//Post something
$('#postDiv').on('keydown', '#posttext', function(e) {
if (e.which==13 && !e.shiftKey && $('#posttext').val()!=' Post something...') {

//This is what I tried to prevent a user from inserting more than one br in a row
var last = false;

var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
if(code == 13) {
    if (last) { e.preventDefault(); }
    last=true;
}else{
    last=false;
}

//If not currently loading and enough text typed in, submit
if($('#imageFeedback').html()!=' | Loading...' && $('#posttext').val().length>15){

    //Say that it is loading
    $('#imageFeedback').css('color','black').css('font-weight','normal').html(' | Loading...');

    //Call function to post
    post($(this));
    return false;
}
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be much better if you simply removed duplicate linebreaks later, e.g. with this regex: `s/\n{2,}/\n/g`

However, to do what you want, simply remove duplicate newlines onkeyup

```
$('#postDiv').on('keyup', '#posttext', function(e) {
    var val = $(this).val(),
        newval = val.replace(/\n{2,}/g, '\n');
    if(val != newval) {
        $(this).val(newval);
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/WJmhF/

Comment: Thank you - however, I need to check it while typing, not later.

Comment: Yeah, see the JavaScript I posted below my suggestion.

Comment: Not quite - it is only about more than one line break in a row. More than one line break in the whole textarea is fine as long as it is not more than one in a row.

Comment: @Dennis How do you define the row?

Comment: @bažmegakapa What I mean by that is just two or more line breaks right after each other.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Looks good! For perfection: how to also prevent the user from inserting more than line break in a row by pressing shift+enter?